# Div didn't toggle on html button

Tags: javascript, html

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5y8fbsn/1/)

I want the div to be hidden when the page will be loaded, and then when you click the button it will show up on the page. But for some reasons it's acting really weird. what should I do?.

HTMl:

```
<p>Don't have an Employee Number?</p> <button id="namebutton">Click Here</button>
<div id="names">
<br>
<p>First name:</p>  <input type="text" name="firstname">
<br><br>
<p>Last name:</p>  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#namebutton").click(function(){
    $("#names").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#names{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSfiddle does not have jQuery included, and your code has a comma after "slow"

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<p>Don't have an Employee Number?</p> <button id="namebutton">Click Here</button>

<div id="names" class="hidden-div">
    <br />
    <p>First name:</p>  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <br /><br />
    <p>Last name:</p>  <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#namebutton").click(function(){
        $("#names").toggleClass("hidden-div", false);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden-div {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See my JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/SolveItSimply/j5y8fbsn/8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript and not jquery, you can try the below function :

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("names").style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById("namebutton").onclick = 'showNames()';
};

function showNames(){
  document.getElementById("names").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

slideToggle doesnt work in this case. :)